# z-index and hyperlinks are not clickable

Tags: css, z-index

I have a footer with position:fixed and z-index:-1 and a body within a table. As long as the content of the body fits into the screen, the hyperlink in the footer is clickable. But when the content of the body needs to be scrolled, the hyperlink in the footer is not clickable anymore.

I tried different position tags and some more stuff but none is of the desired result.

```
.footer {
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  position: fixed;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #2e2929;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: add the codepen to it please. Your use case should be specific here. And try fixing the height here for footer, As it may be overlapping with a element in you want to click.

Comment: Don't know what codepen is. Adding a height-value makes no difference, the footer disappears or is not clickable still.